# Have SQL Server Routinely Check Current Live Tables and Record Into New Table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, windows-server-2008

SQL Server 2014, Windows Server 2008 R2,

I have a database with data that is being constantly updated and old data disposed of. New data has a span of around 5-10 days. The database together has around 50 tables. About 30 tables are constantly being updated whilst the others are fairly stagnant.

What I'd like to achieve, is for a proc to run, say every 10 or so minutes, to record the results from a view I already have in place, to another permanent table.

The purpose is to see snapshots of the data over time for analytical purposes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you facing any issues?

Comment: My question is how do I go about this? How do I create a timed procedure?